# C++ Expression: vector subscript out of range error Line:1733

Tags: c++

When I tried to use this function to remove items in the vector that are NaN

in the following, `unsorted` is a vector filled with items of strings, and `sanitised` is an empty `double` vector

```
...
1 void sensitising(vector <string> unsorted)
2 {
3    double x = 0;
4    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(unsorted); i++)
5    {
6        x = stod(unsorted[i]);
7        if (isnan(x)==false)
8        {
9            sanitised.push_back(x);
10       }
11   }
12}
...
```

an error was thrown at line 6 complaining vector subscript out of range

if line 9 is replaced with `cout << "is a number";` then the error will be thrown after all the items are correctly printed as

```
is a number
is a number
is a number
...
```

any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: It seems as though you are coming from a Python-esque background, where a magic `len(container)` is often what you want. `sizeof` in C++ answers a question you likely have no desire to ask, and to make matters more exciting, it will vary between compilers, yet be constant at runtime, most of the time. For `vector<T>` it is most commonly 24 bytes. That's if the vector is empty, or has as many elements as your address space will permit. At your implicit experience level, look for instance methods that describe your task, rather than global operators which have words/behavior you anticipate.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` does not tell you the length of the vector.  It tells you the size (in bytes) of the actual object.

To get the number of items stored in the vector, use `unsorted.size()`.

Note that in C++11 and later, you can iterate your vector more easily with a range-based loop:

```
for (const auto& str : unsorted) {
    double x = stod(str);
    if (!isnan(x)) {
        sanitised.push_back(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get size of the vector (amount of items), you should use `vector.size()` instead of `sizeof(vector)`, that returns you size of the vector in a memory counted in chars (C++ standard).